# AttributeError in Python and Peewee

Tags: python, peewee

I'm quite new to Python and thus also Peewee.

I have a real simple script set up that gives me the error `AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'Model'` - Can anyone tell me why?

I've got the following script:

```
import peewee
from peewee import *

print dir(peewee)

class User(peewee.Model):
    username = peewee.CharField()
```

- I've tried to make the User class with both `peewee.Model` and just `Model`, as I've found some previous question about a similar error, that stated that it could be the problem, but it doesn't seem to be in my case. I get another error (`NameError: name 'Model' is not defined`) when only using `Model`
- I have updated my peewee to newest version (`sudo pip intall -U peewee`)
- I have tried to run a `print dir(peewee)` which gives me `['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__name__', '__package__', 'peewee']`. I find this a bit odd, since a import math and then dir(math) gives me the functions of math.

The full stack is

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "peewee.py", line 1, in <module>
    import peewee
  File "/home/ubuntu/python/test/peewee.py", line 6, in <module>
    class User(Model):
NameError: name 'Model' is not defined
```

I'm running peewee version 2.2.4 and Python version 2.7.3

I found the script at http://peewee.readthedocs.org/en/latest/peewee/cookbook.html

Comment: Have you tried it without `import peewee` and only `Model`? Just locally tested the referenced example and it's working here without issues.

Comment: Nope, but Padraic Cunningham gave an answer - Thanks for your time though :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have named your file `"/home/ubuntu/python/test/peewee.py"` so Python is trying to import from that instead of the `peewee` module.

Don't use file names that mirror the names of your Python modules. Just rename your `"/home/ubuntu/python/test/peewee.py"` file to something else and it will work.

Comment: I have developed a habit of saving stuff I'm working on under filenames that are not legal Python identifiers. For example, include a hyphen in the filename. This is perfectly legal to run in Python, but it can't be imported, so it will never shadow a built-in module's name.